# Understanding problems in scikit learn in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, scikit-learn

Below is Youtuber Sentdex's machine learning code, and I couldn't understand some parts.

---

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, KMeans
from sklearn import preprocessing, model_selection
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('titanic.xls')
original_df = pd.DataFrame.copy(df)
df.drop(['body', 'name'], 1, inplace=True)
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)


def handle_non_numerical_data(df):
    columns = df.columns.values

    for column in columns:
        text_digit_vals = {}

        def convert_to_int(val):
            return text_digit_vals[val]

        if df[column].dtype != np.int64 and df[column].dtype != np.float64:

            column_contents = df[column].values.tolist()
            unique_elements = set(column_contents)
            x = 0
            for unique in unique_elements:
                if unique not in text_digit_vals:
                    # creating dict that contains new
                    # id per unique string
                    text_digit_vals[unique] = x
                    x += 1
            df[column] = list(map(convert_to_int, df[column]))
    return df


df = handle_non_numerical_data(df)
df.drop(['ticket', 'home.dest'], 1, inplace=True)

X = np.array(df.drop(['survived'], 1).astype(float))
X = preprocessing.scale(X)
y = np.array(df['survived'])

clf = MeanShift()
clf.fit(X)

labels= clf.labels_                          ###Can't understand###
cluster_centers = clf.cluster_centers_
original_df['cluster_group'] = np.nan

for i in range(len(X)):
    original_df['cluster_group'].iloc[i] = labels[i]
n_clusters_ = len(np.unique(labels))
survival_rates = {}
for i in range(n_clusters_):
    temp_df = original_df[(original_df['cluster_group'] == float(i))]
    # print(temp_df.head())

    survival_cluster = temp_df[(temp_df['survived'] == 1)]

    survival_rate = len(survival_cluster) / len(temp_df)
    # print(i,survival_rate)
    survival_rates[i] = survival_rate

print(survival_rates)
```

---

Supposedly in "labels = clf.labels_", labels are [0 : 5] (when I ran program and I got those numbers). But here's the question. Where do those numbers come from? and why 0,1,2? why not bigger number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scikitlearn's [documentation on Meanshift](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.html) provides an explanation of the `labels_` attribute that you seem confused about. Taken directly from the documentation

```
labels_ :
    Labels of each point.
```

If you're more confused about what these labels represent, a brief explanation would be that the number refers to what bin that specific point was clustered into. So all the points with a value of 0 would all belong to the same cluster, and all the points with a value of 1 would all belong to the same cluster, and so on. What the value of these labels are doesn't really matter, they're just here to be able to identify which cluster the data point belongs to.

I'd recommend reading more about clustering if you're still confused about why you would want to label the data.